# X differs from Y in that Z: better way to say it?

Tags: phrase-usage

I wrote:

> De-identification differs from anonymization in that the latter is
>   supposed to be irreversible while the former allows a trusted party to re-identify the data.

To my non-native ears, "*in that*" sounds like basic English. When facing a "*X differs from Y in that Z*" structure, is there a more stylized to phrase it?

I thought of using *whereby*:

> De-identification differs from anonymization whereby data is
>   supposed to be irreversibly anonymized while the former allows a trusted party to re-identify the data.

Comment: No, they mean different things. In the first, the "in that..." clause applies to the **difference**. (The difference lies in the way that...) In the second, the "whereby..." clause applies to the **anonymization**. (Anonymization is the means by which...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*In that* is fine; in fact, it is formal rather than 'basic'.

*Whereby*, on the other hand, is impossible here: it means *by which*, and therefore claims that the fact that de-identification differs from anonymization the means by which the difference you describe comes into being: which makes no sense at all.

The problems with your sentence lie in what follows the subordinator.

1. Properly, what follows *in that* should be structured as a statement which tells the reader how de-identification differs from anonymization  rather than merely describing the two processes and leaving it to the reader to discern how they are different. Specifically, the subject of the *that* clause should be de-identification.
2. *Latter* and *former* have no place in contemporary writing. Your use of them here is time-honoured, its logic is impeccable; but in a complicated sentence like this it puts a wholly unnecessary processing burden on the reader, especially when you flip the terms out of their original order. Readers are not computers, and texts are not programs: find a way of expressing your meaning that doesn't make the reader look up the refrences.

Here are couple of ways to avoid these problems:

> De-identification differs from anonymization in allowing [or *in that it allows*] a trusted party to re-identify the data, where anonymization is supposedly irreversible.
>
> The difference between anonymization and de-identification is that anonymization is supposed to be irreversible but de-identification allows a trusted party to re-identify the data.

These are a little bit longer than your sentence, but they're a lot easier to follow.

I have no idea what that *supposedly* means, so you might want to clean that up, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer! (I used *supposedly* to lay emphasis on the fact that in many instances anonymization turned out to be reversible, e.g. in the $1-Million Netflix Prize some people managed to de-anonymized part of the dataset)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I suggest then that you write "anonymization is supposed to be" - *supposedly* has more of the original sense of *it is supposed that*.